# Javascript Time Display am/pm from Computer (quick tweak)

Tags: javascript, time, clock, code-snippets

Just need a quick tweak if thats ok. I got this code from the web and would just like to add an am/pm to be displayed at the end of the clock/time. Many thanks...

```
<script>
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
```

```
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or, if you also want it displayed in 12-hour format:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function startTime()
{
var today=new Date();
var h=today.getHours();
var m=today.getMinutes();
var s=today.getSeconds();
// add a zero in front of numbers<10
m=checkTime(m);
s=checkTime(s);
var hd=h;
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=(hd=0?"12":hd>12?hd-12:hd)+":"+m+":"+s+" "+(h<12?"AM":"PM");
t=setTimeout(function(){startTime()},500);
}

function checkTime(i)
{
if (i<10)
  {
  i="0" + i;
  }
return i;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, would like it to be 12 hour clock for sure, but this above code isn't quite working. Care to fix? It starts from 12:00 am instead of the actual time

Comment: Sorry, I meant 3 hours after the time on my computer

Comment: Interesting. It is displaying the time correctly on my system. However, it is currently ~1:30 AM in my time zone. Does the time display correctly on your system using your original code?

Comment: Yep, the original code displays the correct time according to my computer

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);

    var suffix;        
    if (h >= 12 && h < 24){
        suffix = "pm";
    } else {
        suffix = "am";
    }    
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + suffix;

    t = setTimeout(function () {
        startTime()
    }, 500);
}

function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {
        i = "0" + i;
    }
    return i;
}
```